# Translating decoded multi-swap transactions into Buys/Sells

Tags: transactions, tokens, uniswap, python, moralis

How can I determine if a transaction is a buy or a sale of a certain token?

I'm taking as an example this multi-swap transaction:
[image]

Decoded tx data from Moralis: https://pastebin.com/xhtFrnb2

Right now I wrote a function in Python iterating for all the logs and recording token0 and token1 with transfer events, while 'closing' the single swap after a swap transaction, but it seems like there could be a transfer of a certain token also after the swap transaction, that does not concern the next swap.

I'm looking for a passe-partout way to analyze a swap transaction and get an output similar to the one of Etherscan. All the help is deeply appreciated.